# how to display data from CTypedPtrArray in CView

Tags: c++, mfc, oledb

I have a CTypedPtrArray with information in my CitiesTableDoc.cpp and I wanna visualize this elements in a table(CitiesTableView.cpp file) like the one in the Sql Server.
The Cities table has 5 columns(id, updateCounter, name, area, postCode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a CListView instead of a CView.

With a CListView you have a full CListCTrl and you can set it up in Report mode.
Add rows and set the Sub items.

With SetItemData you can save a pointer in the list control that Points back to your origonal data.